# C# Entity Framework Table Per Type adding unwanted column in base table

Tags: entity-framework-4

In C# I'm using Entity Framework and MVC and have:

```
public class Part

public class FinishedGoodsPart: Part
   public int? ProductLineId { get; set; }

public class CompetitorPart : Part
   public int? ProductLineId { get; set; }

public class OEPart: Part

public class ProductLine
   public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
```

Observe that FinishedGoodsPart and CompetitorPart have a ProductLine, but OEPart does not.

This puts a column called ProductLine_Id in the FinishedGoodsPart and CompetitorPart tables, as I expect and want, but also puts column ProductLine_Id in table Part (which I do not want).

How do I prevent E.F. from adding column Part.ProductLine_Id? Is there a better design?

The goal is that an instance of the ProductLine model object will have a list of all parts which belong to that product line (whether they are competitor or finished goods parts). But an OEPart is not allowed to have a ProductLine set.

FinishedGoodsPart objects will have a lot of attributes, whereas CompetitorPart will have very few, therefore I don't want to store all part records in a single database table.

Comment: `ProductLine.Parts` defines a relationship between `ProductLine` and `Part`. EF can't but create a foreign key for it in `Part`.

Comment: Is there a better solution? Ideally I'd like one list on the ProductLine object that lists all parts (regardless of subclass) associated to it.